# python signature of method in diamond derived class

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

I am wondering what is the signature in a class derived from 2 classes that have a common but different method.

For example

```
class Base1():
    def __init__(a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Base2():
    def __init__(c):
        self.c = c

class Derived(Base1, Base2):

    def do_something():
        return 3
```

What is the signature of the `init` method is the `Derived` class?
What is its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a new signature. Instead, the first method in the *method resolution order* will be used. In your case that's `Base1.__init__`.